# Как высчитывать и округлять прошедшие месяцы имея дату?

Tags: javascript, frontend, дата, ecmascript-6

есть блоки которые выводятся в цикле и у которых есть дата активности например 121 день назад у конкретного итема. С бэкенда приходит дата этой последней активности которую я форматирую через JS  в обычный формат "2022.04.13" , задача состоит в том нужно чтобы система высчитывала месяца и округляла в таком формате:
From 30 to 41d = 1m ago
From 41 to 51- 1.5m ago
From from 51 to 71 - 2m ago
ну и так далее +-10 дней для каждого месяца.

У меня написана функция но она всего лишь выводит сколько прошло месяцев без необходимых в условиях задачи диапазонов и плавающих чисел по типу  1.5 месяцев

```
 const monthAgo = (endDate) => {
  const date = new Date();
  let monthInitial = date.getMonth();
  const monthCalc = monthInitial++;
  const month = monthCalc < 10 ? '0' + monthCalc : monthCalc;
  const day = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
  let startDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
  startDate = new Date(startDate);

  let dateEnd = endDate.slice(0, 10);
  dateEnd = new Date(dateEnd);

  let calcMonthAgo = Math.round((startDate.getTime()-dateEnd.getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24*30) + 1);

  return calcMonthAgo;
}
```

Запутался как сделать мне чтоб работало как написано в требованиях?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так:

```js
const monthAgo = (endDate) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const days = Math.round((date - endDate) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
  const months = Math.floor(days / 30);
  const rest = days % 30;
  console.log(days, months, rest);
  return rest < 11 ? months.toString() + 'm' : rest < 21 ? months.toString() + '.5 m' : (months + 1).toString() + 'm';
}

let lastDate = new Date("2022-03-13");
console.log(lastDate, monthAgo(lastDate));

lastDate = new Date("2022-09-01");
console.log(lastDate, monthAgo(lastDate));

lastDate = new Date("2022-08-23");
console.log(lastDate, monthAgo(lastDate));
```